# Can you type hint overload a return type for a method based on an argument passed into the constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, type-hinting

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__ (self, param1: Tuple[str,...], param2: bool) -> None:
        self.member1 = param1
        self.member2 = param2
        self.member3 = 10

    def gimmie(self) -> int | Tuple[str,...]:
        return self.member1 if self.member2 else self.member3
```

Is there any way I can ensure that the return from gimmie is **not** of type `int | Tuple[str,...]` but rather is an `int` **or** `Tuple[str,...]`?

**Edit:**

There are a couple answers that involve significant acrobatics to do this, when all I really was looking to do was `cast` the return. Each of those answers both comment on a code "smell" because of this.

The problem is simply that I construct an object with a flag and one of the methods returns 1 of 2 types based on that flag. If that's bad design, what would be the "correct" way to do it?

Comment: Could you use generics and wrap the constructor in a factory function?

Comment: @Samwise No idea, please elaborate.

Comment: I think you need to have the return type be tied to the class type.  So one way would be to have the class be a generic, e.g. `myclass[int]` vs `myclass[Tuple[str,...]]`.  Another way (maybe the way I'd go) would be to have subclasses with different method signatures.

Comment: @Samwise I'm not familiar with generics, I'll need to look into that. For the latter, how would you defer the return to the subclasses?

Comment: Similar to what you're doing with `@overload`, give the parent class the union type and have implementations in the subclasses that narrow it.

Comment: @Samwise I'm not sure I understand the semantics. Whatever calls `myclass.gimmie()` sees the return type of that method, so how would they be able to see the return types of the subclasses? Wouldn't I have to call `subclass.gimmie()` instead? I don't know which subclass I need until after `myclass.gimmie()` has been called.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to solve this with generics:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import overload, Literal, Generic, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar('T')


class myclass(Generic[T]):
    member1: tuple[str, ...]
    member2: bool
    member3: int

    @overload
    def __init__(self: myclass[tuple[str, ...]], param1: tuple[str, ...], param2: Literal[True]) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: myclass[int], param1: tuple[str, ...], param2: Literal[False]) -> None:
        ...

    def __init__(self, param1: tuple[str, ...], param2: bool) -> None:
        self.member1 = param1
        self.member2 = param2
        self.member3 = 10

    def gimmie(self) -> T:
        return cast(T, self.member1 if self.member2 else self.member3)


reveal_type(myclass(('a', 'b'), True).gimmie())
# note: Revealed type is "builtins.tuple*[builtins.str]"

reveal_type(myclass(('a', 'b'), False).gimmie())
# note: Revealed type is "builtins.int*"
```

Some notes:

- This approach requires annotating the `self` argument to give it a different static type. Usually, we don't annotate `self`, so make sure not to forget this!
- Sadly I could not get `a if b else c` to have the right type without adding a `cast`.

I do agree with Samwise that this kind of type judo is a code smell, and might be hiding problems with the design of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but all I was missing was knowledge of the cast function. I definitely don't need to do anything crazy. This is some useful info here about Generics and TypeVars though, thank you.

Comment: Note that this only really works if the `member2` attribute is considered immutable. `mypy` can't detect if you do something like `obj = myclass(("foo", "bar"), True); obj.member2 = False; y: int = obj.gimmie()`, and will flag this as an error even though at run time `obj.gimmie` will return an `int`.

Comment: @chepner True. I should have used `member2: Final[bool]` to catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to tackle it with subclasses and an `@overload`ed factory function:

```
from typing import Literal, Tuple, Union, cast, overload


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param1: Tuple[str, ...], param2: bool) -> None:
        self.member1 = param1
        self.__member2 = param2
        self.member3 = 10

    def gimmie(self) -> Union[int, Tuple[str, ...]]:
        return self.member1 if self.__member2 else self.member3


class _MySubclass1(MyClass):
    def gimmie(self) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
        return cast(Tuple[str, ...], MyClass.gimmie(self))


class _MySubclass2(MyClass):
    def gimmie(self) -> int:
        return cast(int, MyClass.gimmie(self))


@overload
def myclass(param1: Tuple[str, ...], param2: Literal[True]) -> _MySubclass1:
    ...


@overload
def myclass(param1: Tuple[str, ...], param2: Literal[False]) -> _MySubclass2:
    ...


def myclass(param1: Tuple[str, ...], param2: bool) -> MyClass:
    if param2:
        return _MySubclass1(param1, param2)
    else:
        return _MySubclass2(param1, param2)


myobj1 = myclass((), True)
myobj2 = myclass((), False)
reveal_type(myobj1.gimmie())  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[builtins.str]"
reveal_type(myobj2.gimmie())  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

Note that this is a lot of work and requires careful attention to make sure the `cast`s match the implementation logic -- I don't know the real-world problem you're trying to solve, but having to go through this much trouble to make the typing line up correctly is often a "smell" in the way you're modeling the data.

Comment: cast! That's all I really needed. I can just cast the result. That's mainly all I was looking for. What you have here is def overkill and is not what I was trying to do, I don't need a factory function.

The real world problem is simply that I set a flag when I make an object, and then one of its methods can return 2 different results based on that flag. I just needed to make sure I didn't get any type errors on the return type if I started treating it as one or the other. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with using `cast` (and the reason you'd potentially want to bury it under all this stuff) is that it eliminates the benefit of type checking at the point where you use it.  If a user of your interface needs to `cast` in order to be able to use the result, you might as well just not declare a type in the first place.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't see another solution that's anywhere near as clean or straight forward. The method can simply return one of two types based on the way the object was constructed. That's it. I don't know how else you would type hint the return. It doesn't seem to be that unusual or complicated of a problem, unless I'm missing something. To be clear, the scope where I construct the object is the same scope that's receiving the result, so it has knowledge of the type it will return, I'm just type hinting it to be consistent.

Comment: The fact that the method has differing return types is really the root of the problem, and that's the part I'd need to know more about to provide a better solution.  It seems like more of an interface design problem than a coding/typing problem.

Comment: Ok. The class is one that continuously parses and monitors the stdout of another process on another thread. The stdout continuously provides the current progress in time as hrs:mins:secs and is being piped into that class. The flag I pass into the constructor is whether to return that time as a list [hrs, mins, secs], or as a percentage; i.e. calculate hrs:mins:secs as (totalseconds/completeseconds)*100, aka an int. The progress is only returned when I call a method asking for it.

Comment: I'd just have the monitoring class return a single type (like a tuple of `timedelta`s) and leave it up to another piece of code to translate that into different formats (like an `as_percent` function and an `as_string` function that take the same input type and return different output types).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: I thought about that as well but figured it would be unnecessary to create an entirely new function or method to handle something that can be handled by a single parameter. Especially since the point of the class is to encapsulate functionality related to parsing this information and this is just a type hinting issue. Either way, thanks for your input.