# Python typing return type of class composition's method

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a class `Human` which can have a pet and a method to make it talk, either a `Dog` or a `Cat`. I initialize the `Human` with a `Dog`, and the method `pet_speak` has the correct return type hint `Literal["Woof"]`.

If I change the `Human`'s pet to a `Cat` after initialization, the method return type hint isn't updated to `Literal["Meow"]`.

Is there a way to change this behavior? This is a simplified version of my problem, creating two classes, such as, `HumanDog` and `HumanCat` is more complex.

```py
class Cat:
    def speak(self): # implicit return type hint Literal["Meow"]
        return "Meow"

class Dog:
    def speak(self): # implicit return type hint Literal["Woof"]
        return "Woof"

# Class `Human` has a `pet`, and can call its `speak()` method
class Human:
    pet = Dog()

    def pet_speak(self):
        return self.pet.speak()

# Helper function to change `human`'s pet
def change_pet(human):
    human.pet = Cat()
    return human

bob = Human()
woof = bob.pet_speak() # Return type is correctly Literal["Woof"]
bob = change_pet(bob) # change attribute `pet` to `Cat`
meow = bob.pet_speak() # Return type is Literal["Woof"], but should be Literal["Meow"]
```

The closest question I could find was [Can you type hint overload a return type for a method based on an argument passed into the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70136046/), but it also adds an overhead to every `Human` method and subclasses.

---

Sorry if I dumbed the problem down too much, here it's more similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Api:
    def request(self):
        return "Response"

class AsyncApi:
    async def request(self):
        return "Response"

class Database:
    api: Api | AsyncApi = Api()

    def get(self):
        return self.api.request()

def Async(database):
    database.api = AsyncApi()
    return database


async def main():
    db = Database()
    db.get()
    adb = Async(db)
    await adb.get() # typing error
```

Comment: You can't use a literal for the return type of `Human.pet_speak()` because the type of `Human.pet` can be anything.

Comment: You should define an abstract base class for all pets, and specify the general return type (e.g. `str`) for all of their `speak()` methods.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the help! I can define `Human.pet` as `Cat | Dog` but the problem is still there. Having a general type doesn't help, I need the type hint to be exactly the only possible outcome, `Literal["Woof"]` or `Literal["Meow"]`.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a more realistic example? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: > { but it also adds an overhead to every Human method and subclasses. }

Could you elaborate what you mean by "overhead" here?

Comment: It makes little sense to be so specific in the `Human` class. Next you'll want to add `bird`, later you'll add other types of pet. So all you can really say is that `petspeak()` will return a string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @decorator-factory. The overhead I mean is that I have to add `cast(T, ...)` to every new method, but I think this might indeed be the best way to do it. Sorry if my original problem wasn't too clear, I updated the answer with one more similar to what I'm having.

Comment: @Leonardo ah, I see now :) Well, keeping both a sync and async client with DRY code seems like an unsolved problem, at least in Python (unless you want to mention the M-word). If there aren't dozens of requests I would just make two classes to be honest. This is also more flexible: if you need to make two requests in a single method or if you want to make retries, your way will not really work.

Comment: @decorator-factory what would the `M-word` be? I just want to solve this problem, and I have no strong opinions :) Duplicating the class is more complicated, since I have more than one `Database` class

Comment: The M-word is "monad" - it's a construct from functional programming that lets you, for example, write a single piece of code that will work in both synchronous and asynchronous context ([this article explains it](https://sobolevn.me/2020/06/how-async-should-have-been)). I doubt it's relevant here, but it's a path one can take

Comment: Why do you have these `Database` classes? Why not just use the `*Api` classes directly? Is there something more to the `Database` classes maybe?

Comment: I don't think I would restructure the entire codebase with Monads to accomodate this. For now the answer to the other question I posted will do it, using generics and overload.

`Database`s are some interfaces to some services API's. So let's say I want to create a `Youtube` class, it will have an `api_client`, either sync or async, and maybe some methods specific to it, such as `upload_video`, `like`, `report`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the missing annotation run the code through Pyright (or Mypy), it will spot an error here:

```py
def change_pet(human: Human) -> None:
    human.pet = Cat()
    # ^
    # Cannot assign member "pet" for type "Human"
    #  Expression of type "Cat" cannot be assigned to member "pet" of class "Human"
    #    "Cat" is incompatible with "Dog"
    return human
```

Indeed, the type of `human.pet` is `Cat`. Generally, the type of an object can't change when you're mutating it. This makes sense, for example because an object might be shared:

```py
class CatHumans:
    def __init__(self, humans: Iterable[Human]) -> None:
        # somehow establish that all the `humans` have a cat
        self._humans = list(humans)

    def do_something_assuming_humans_have_cats(self) -> None:
        for human in self._humans:
            assert human.pet.speak() == "Meow"
            ...

alice, bob, charlie = make_humans_with_cats(3)
cat_humans = CatHumans([alice, bob, charlie])

alice.pet = Dog()
cat_humans.do_something_assuming_humans_have_cats()
```

It would be very difficult if not impossible for type checkers to track situations like this.

---

I don't know what real problem you're solving, but I have two solutions:

1. Specify a more general type for `pet`:

A common protocol/base class:

```py
class Human:
    pet: Animal = Dog()
```

Or a union type:

```py
from typing import Union

class Human:
    pet: Union[Cat, Dog] = Dog()
```

2. Make a generic class

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

Pet = TypeVar("Pet", bound=Animal)

class Human(Generic[Pet]):
    def __init__(self, pet: Pet) -> None:
        self.pet = pet
```

This still doesn't let you have the same object be `Human[Dog]` today and `Human[Cat]` tomorrow, but you can have distinct `Human[Cat]` and `Human[Dog]` objects.